# Анимация метки "подскок"

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

как можно реализовать анимацию метки со своим изображением метки в виде циклического "подскока/отскока" этой метки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: в песочнице есть следующий пример: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_layout
но это не цикличная анимация. как создать именно цикличную анимацию метки из своего макета?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать анимированные гифки в качестве источника изображения метки, прописав адрес в опциях:

```
iconLayout: 'default#image',
iconImageHref: 'image.gif'
```

Пример: https://jsbin.com/xujujij/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Либо сгенерируйте поведение метки через CSS. Пульсирующую метку тут [показывал ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1145086/386299). Если фидл недоступен (будь он неладен!), вот вариант на jsbin: https://jsbin.com/netanoj/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Спасибо . вариант c gif понятен, но не лучший для меня вариант: нужно хранить и статичное изображение и анимированное для каждой метки. Хотелось бы разобраться с CSS но знаний не хватает.
нет ли примера с анимацией своей пиктограммки .png ?